# Should all local users with the same username have the same UID in all the machines of an organization?

Tags: linux, user-management

We have a datacenter environment where there are servers with the username "java" that has the UID 5000. Now, we are creating the same local user, "java", in some thinclients.

- Is it important that the username "java" in the thinclients has the
  same UID than the username "java" in the datacenter?
- How does an organization control that all local users with the same username use
  the same UID?

Comment: "Should all local users with the same username have the same UID in all the machines of an organization?" - seems like a question for yourself, but if there is no need for it, why do it

Comment: @JOW Because if you copy a file mantaining the permissions you may get a file in the target with a owner that may be not who you expect...for example.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily required. Having said that, there is not enough information provided to see the full picture of where the thin clients come in touch with the servers. You can do that for the sake of easily aligning all Java applications and users under the same uid. If however, the thin clients mount the remote directories from these servers ( nfs maybe), then matching the GID and UID does help in access management.

Normally, to control the UID and GID allocation, you will have some sort of directory setup like ldap or Active Directory or something similar. On the other hand, if you have a decent configuration management system like ansible, or puppet, you can then control it (akin to deploy) using scripts.